# How to put expandable ListView inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, expandablelistview

I can't seem to scroll in my fragment. I have an expandable listview in the middle of editText and textViews and a textView and editText below the expandable listview. I can't scroll down to the bottom textView and editText. How do I format this so I can scroll all the way down without having to touch the listView?

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="edu.bradley.apawelczyk.trackapp.Add_Athlete_Fragment"
android:weightSum="1"
android:padding="20dp"
android:id="@+id/addAthleteLayout">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add New Athlete"
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:text="Name: "
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/editFirstName"
    android:hint="First Name"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
    android:textColorHint="#BBBBBB"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/editLastName"
    android:hint="Last Name"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
    android:textColorHint="#BBBBBB"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtAge"
    android:text="Age: "
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/editAge"
    android:hint=""
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
    android:textColorHint="#BBBBBB"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtGrade"
    android:text="Grade: "
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/editGrade"
    android:hint=""
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
    android:textColorHint="#BBBBBB"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtEvent"
    android:text="Event: "
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
<ExpandableListView
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/eventsList"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#000000"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:focusable="false">
</ExpandableListView>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtTier"
    android:text="Tier: "
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/editTier"
    android:hint=""
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
    android:textColorHint="#BBBBBB"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The layout you are trying to create would not work this way, `ListView` is not meant to be in `ScrollView` because the touch events will get consumed. For a `ListView` with scrollable headers you have to add those with [`addHeaderView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) method (similar for footers). However, this cannot be done just with XML.

Your main XML should only contain the `ExpandableListView`, then I would suggest to create one XML with `LinearLayout` containing all the views you want to have above the `ListView` and another XML with the views that will be bellow. In your code just inflate those XMLs and call `addHeaderView()` and `addFooterView()` with them. Also if you use `onItemClickListener` note that header view will shift the index of views.

Answer (score 0):

Expandable listview/listview do not recieve gestures because the scrollview handles them. Try changing your layout.

Comment: How would I change my layout?